# Mark intersections with custom shape (TikZ)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to mark the intersections between `\path` and `curve` with circles and triangle. My circles are fine. But i have a problem with my triangle. The triangle indicates the direction of the curve, it's kind of an arrow. Maybe [this](https://ibb.co/4prRGzW) helps you to understand what i'm talking about.

Here, is my MWE. For the convenient, i comment the error part.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows.meta, intersections}
\def\trigl{iscoceles triangle[width=1.4mm, rotate=-3]}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[-stealth] (0,0) -- (6.7,0) 
            node[right]{$x$}; %x-axis
        \draw[-stealth] (0,0) -- (0,3) 
            node[above]{$y$}; %y-axis
        \draw [thick, name path=curve1,{Circle[length=1.4mm]}-{Circle[length=1.4mm]}]
            (0.2,1) .. controls (2,.6) and (2.7,.6) .. (2.9,1.5) 
                    .. controls (3.1,2.7) and (4,3) .. (6.5,1.8);
        \path [name path = line1] (1,0)--(1,3.5) (1.4,0)--(1.4,3.5) (2.3,0)--(2.3,3.5) (2.7,0)--(2.7,3.5) (2.93,0)--(2.93,3.5) (3.25,0)--(3.25,3.5) (3.6,0)--(3.6,3.5) (4.4,0)--(4.4,3.5) (5.3,0)--(5.3,3.5) (5.7,0)--(5.7,3.5);
        \fill [name intersections={of=curve1 and line1, name=i}]
        \foreach \s in {1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10}{(i-\s) circle (2pt)};
%       \fill [name intersections={of=curve1 and line1, name=i}] {(i-5) \trigl (2pt)};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Like this](https://i.imgur.com/NOcPeKb.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the shape of `node` by `regular polygon sides=3` (if it is a polygon) or `circle` or `square` etc, instead of defining new shape. You can also rotate it if its direction is not desired by `rotate=30` or any amount.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows.meta, intersections}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[-stealth] (0,0) -- (6.7,0) 
            node[right]{$x$}; %x-axis
        \draw[-stealth] (0,0) -- (0,3) 
            node[above]{$y$}; %y-axis
        \draw [thick, name path=curve1,{Circle[length=1.4mm]}-{Circle[length=1.4mm]}]
            (0.2,1) .. controls (2,.6) and (2.7,.6) .. (2.9,1.5) 
                    .. controls (3.1,2.7) and (4,3) .. (6.5,1.8);
        \path [name path = line1] (1,0)--(1,3.5) (1.4,0)--(1.4,3.5) (2.3,0)--(2.3,3.5) 
       (2.7,0)--(2.7,3.5) (2.93,0)--(2.93,3.5) (3.25,0)--(3.25,3.5) (3.6,0)--(3.6,3.5) 
       (4.4,0)--(4.4,3.5) (5.3,0)--(5.3,3.5) (5.7,0)--(5.7,3.5);
        \fill [name intersections={of=curve1 and line1, name=i}]
        \foreach \s in {1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10}{(i-\s) circle (2pt)};
       \path [name intersections={of=curve1 and line1, name=i}] (i-5) node[regular 
      polygon,regular polygon sides=3, fill,inner sep=1pt] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]